# Unity CardboardVR packages instead of application

Tags: android, ios, unity-game-engine, google-cardboard, virtual-reality

I'm planning to develop a mobile application (android/ios) which can download and view google cardboard supported VR contents. I will be creating these contents separately. Is it possible? How can I achieve this?

Would be great if one can at least point me in the right direction, I don't need an end to end guide.

Comment: An important question is from where would you want users to download these new packages from. Is it the play store, each as a new app or perhaps from your own server with some in-app menu?

Answer (score 0):

If by "supported VR contents" you mean panoramic images and videos you can create these medias separately and download them to your Unity application using the classes [WWW](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/WWW.html) or [WWWForm](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/WWWForm.html).